# Asymptotics of $\sum_{n\leq x}d(2n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the sum of the number of divisors:$\ \sum_{n\leq x}d(n)=x\log x+(2\gamma-1)x+O(\sqrt{x}),$ what is $\sum_{n\leq x}d(2n)$ asymptotic to? Is there a generalisation for $\sum_{n\leq x}d(k n),\ k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Best say what the function $d(n)$ is. Is it the number of divisors of $n$? 
"Sum of divisors" makes it onfusing - you mean the sum of the number of divisors.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, sorry, I do- will update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $D(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} d(n)$, we have
$\sum_{n \leq x} d(2n) = 2D(x) - D(x/2)$ because $d(2n) = 2 d(n)$ or
$2d(n) - d(n/2)$ according as $n$ is even or odd.  There are similar identities
that reduce any $\sum_{n \leq x} d(kn)$ to a linear combination of values of $D$ at multiples of $x$.

Comment: brilliant! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you!